# Unable to properly setup navbar in responsive mode using Next JS and Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, next.js, chakra-ui

I have been trying to build a website using Next JS and Chakra UI and I wanted to make it responsive. So I have used the react-responsive package to do so. My initial goal is to make a responsive navbar. The working is as follows:

In desktop mode, this is the output I am expecting:

[image: Light Mode Desktop]
[image: Dark Mode Desktop]

The toggling happens perfectly from light mode to dark mode. For the mobile mode, I would want to have a hamburger instead of the navbar, which on being clicked has a Drawer Chakra UI element to show all navbar contents.

[image: Mobile hamburger]

While all of this has been implemented as expected, a small bug seems to have occurred. I am getting the hamburger icon instead of the Moon Icon every time I refresh the page in desktop mode.

Here is a quick demo of the issue I have been facing

[image]

I have attached the corresponding code for this part

Importing packages and assigning variables, We are concerned about `isBigScreen`

```js
import { SunIcon, MoonIcon, HamburgerIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';


const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();
const bg = useColorModeValue(navBgColor.light, navBgColor.dark);
const isBigScreen = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 600 });
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
```

Then I am returning a NavContainer which essentially is a Flex with some configs.

```js
return (
        <NavContainer
            flexDirection="row"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            alignItems="center"
            maxWidth="900px"
            width="100%"
            bg={bg}
            as="nav"
            p={8}
            mt={[0, 8]}
            mb={8}
            mx="auto"
        >
             .
             .
             .
        // Code inside this is mentioned below
             . 
             . 

        </NavContainer>
    );
```

This part of the code sets up the color toggler on the left. This has been taken from the example code in react-responsive readme

```js
            {isBigScreen && (
                <IconButton
                    aria-label="toggle dark mode"
                    icon={colorMode == 'dark' ? <SunIcon /> : <MoonIcon />}
                    onClick={toggleColorMode}
                />
            )}
```

This is the part of the code which I feel is causing an issue

This part of the code makes sure that if the screen is desktop then show navbar with the Links (home, about, projects, blog) in the same row as shown in image 1 and 2, and if this is not in desktop mode, then show a hamburger icon.

```js
            {isBigScreen ? (
                    <Box>{LINKS.map(getLink)}</Box> 
                ) : (
                    <IconButton
                        aria-label="toggle ham"
                        icon={<HamburgerIcon />}
                        onClick={onOpen}
                    />                    
                )}
```

This part of the code takes care of the situation when it is in mobile mode where a drawer is sliding from left. This is also working perfectly.

```js
            <Drawer isOpen={isOpen} placement="left" onClose={onClose}>
                <DrawerOverlay>
                    <DrawerContent>
                        <DrawerCloseButton />
                        <DrawerBody>
                            <Flex
                                direction="column"
                                justifyContent="center"
                                height="100%"
                                alignItems="center"
                            >
                                <IconButton
                                    boxSize="50px"
                                    mb="6"
                                    aria-label="toggle dark mode"
                                    icon={colorMode === 'dark' ? <SunIcon /> : <MoonIcon />}
                                    onClick={toggleColorMode}
                                />
                                {LINKS.map(getLink)}
                            </Flex>
                        </DrawerBody>
                    </DrawerContent>
                </DrawerOverlay>
            </Drawer>
```

If any further clarification is required, I would be glad to help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
import { colorMode, useColorMode } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';

const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();

<Button onClick={toggleColorMode}>
  {colorMode === 'light' ? <MoonIcon /> : <SunIcon />}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I can't say without seeing your full-code, but I would forget the react-responsive library and just set your breakpoints and your `display` property on your menu with this `display={['none', 'none', 'flex', 'flex']}` and the reverse for your hamburger.